# Display or say the current daytime ticks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm experimenting with some redstone and need to get a running display of what the current daytime ticks are. I'm working in a single player creative world.

I can get this manually by running "/time query daytime".

However, when I put the time command into a command block and trigger it with redstone, no output is displayed in the chat.

I've also ensured that "commandBlockOutput" is set to true.

I'll be triggering the command block on a timing circuit. How can I get the results to display in chat or in some other way?

Answer (score 1):

You can store it in a scoreboard using `/execute store`.

Preparation:

```
/scoreboard objectives add scoreboard_name dummy
```

Storing the time in a scoreboard:

```
execute store result score $gametime scoreboard_name run time query daytime
```

And then you can display it like any other score with `/tellraw`:

```
tellraw @p {"score":{"name":"$gametime","objective":"scoreboard_name"}}
```

`scoreboard_name` is an arbitrary chosen scoreboard name, `$gametime` an arbitrarily chosen fake player name that cannot possibly be the same as a real player name. Start it with `#` if you want to hide it from scoreboard sidebar displays.